# How to set proper constraints on my UITable Cells. Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I am new to swift and i am have a little trouble with setting up the proper constraints for my table.

I have a table which get filled using an array. I have three subviews which need to be placed underneath each other. This is the result im getting:

[image]

As you can see a part of my orange cell is being cut off by the red cell.  (i have tried multiple other constraints but this is the closest i have gotten to the desired effect.

I do understand why this is happening. Its because i put a bottomAnchor on the parentView with a topAnchor of mainView and i also do the same for the commentView.

I would think the proper setting would be to change the constraint into:

```
parentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.commentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.parentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

But this removes the mainView from the screen. resulting in:

[image]

How can i get them neatly underneath each other?

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.addSubview(commentView)
        self.addSubview(parentView)
        self.addSubview(mainView)

        parentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        parentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        parentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        parentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        parentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true


        mainView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true



        commentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        commentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        commentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        commentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    }
```

The desired result would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post what's your desired design look like? Another thing, tried `StackView` before?

Comment: i added a picture of what i basicly want. (minus the content obviously but this needs to be setup)

Orange
Gray
Red
Orange 
Gray 
Red

and so on

Comment: i checked out stackView which is interesting but not sure how i would set different heights for each element. (i dont use storyboards)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it. solved it by changing it into a stackview with the follow added code:

```
var parentView : UITextView = {
    var textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.backgroundColor = orangeBanner
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
    return textView

}()

var mainView : UITextView = {
    var textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    textView.backgroundColor = grayBanner
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
    return textView

}()

var commentView : UITextView = {
    var textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0).isActive = true
    return textView

}()

lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [parentView, mainView, commentView])
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.axis = .vertical
    sv.spacing = 0

    return sv

}()


self.addSubview(stackView)

stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!